# How does deep learning work in real time?

Tags: api, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I just have made api which recommends movies based on user input using Django. It’s designed as to execute deep learning function for every 10 inputs from each user. For this each 10 inputs, it takes around 10 seconds to give output. How does google or amazon can do real time data update without delay?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to execution there is no deep **learning**, there is just **deep model**. Let us assume that this is a regular feed forward model, then all you have to do is perform K (depth) matrix multiplications. For convolutional layers it is much more, but still matrix multiplications. All these operations are **extremely simple** to parallelize. In particular just running them on GPU will give you ~20x boost. Using tensorflow which can scatter computations across many cores/cpus/machines also works the same way. There are also numerous other optimizations possible, like training a small net to replicate behaviour of the big one, making use of sparsity of some matrices (if you are using relus - many neurons will produce zeros, thus - sparse matrices appear) etc.

That being said - network that takes 10s to process 10 inputs sounds like a horrible implementation, or the network is really **huge**, so before going for general optimization schemes - make sure your current code is fine. For example if you use tensorflow etc. it is important that many things **before** pushing your data take time - like loading libraries, starting sessions, session .run call itself etc.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I just used apriori algorithm for that. I will try with TensorFlow later. My main question is I don't know how to update(train) all these data with new users input in parallel while allowing users to access to that database. How can I automate deep learning trainig to update data without making any trouble(like slowing down) and so forth?

Comment: Now this is a completely different question, and usually these are two separate things. You have one model that is actually being used for prediction (lets call it A), then you have another that is being trained (B), and you only synchronize these models from time to time (copying B to A). Both things on separate machines etc. this way there is no slowdown even though the model is training "in parallel". Important advantage of such an approach is that you can also test whether newly trained model is good enough before pushing it into production (copying to A)

Comment: So whenever I google something, they use machine B to calculate while providing prediction from machine A. and those machines are fast enough to synchronize to each other to give me updated prediction whenever I try to search something else relate to previous one in 10 sec? Sorry, Im still beginner.

Comment: Google does not train their models on your single queries, training of big models requires lots of data, a single query is not worth calculating the gradients. What you are referring to (having something "remembered") has nothing to do with training in parallel, you can always use previous queries as a context, this does not require retraining anything.

Comment: I see. So it seems like creating parallel training and predicting for every incoming data has long ways to go. It's confusing to detect in which part deep learning is used for application though, it's certainly developing. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is possible, but simply makes very little sense, it is better to "learn to adapt" (in the sense of training a model, then can actually interact) than "retrain in order to adapt" (as you would need a separate model per user, or maybe even per usecase).

Comment: I just found this and your answer were also in there. Very interesting. Thank you anyways :) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.07792v1.pdf